# Calculate UITableView's height using its content size height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom UIView that contains an UITableView with items. I have a variable that stores the UITableView's height constraint and I want to use that constraint to expand and collapse the table.

That table is not scrollable, the height of that table should be based on its content.

The table's cells have auto-layout, so the cell's height is calculated based on its content too.

This is the code of my table:

```
     expandedTableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain).then {
        $0.dataSource = self
        $0.delegate = self
        $0.backgroundColor = .clear
        $0.register(YTDropdownItemCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: YTDropdownItemCell.identifier)
        $0.tableFooterView = UIView()
        $0.isScrollEnabled = false
        $0.separatorStyle = .none
        $0.alpha = 0.0
        $0.estimatedRowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

    expandedTableView.topAnchor == collapsedView.bottomAnchor
    expandedTableView.horizontalAnchors == collapsedView.horizontalAnchors
    expandedHeightConstraint = expandedTableView.heightAnchor == 0
    expandedTableView.bottomAnchor == contentView.bottomAnchor

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: YTDropdownItemCell.identifier,
                                                for: indexPath) as? YTDropdownItemCell {
                cell.configureCellItem(item: items[indexPath.row])
                return cell
         }

         return YTDropdownItemCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: YTDropdownItemCell.identifier)
     }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
          return UITableView.automaticDimension
     }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
          return UITableView.automaticDimension
     }

     private func tableAnimation() {
          expandedTableView.setNeedsLayout()
          expandedTableView.reloadData()
          expandedTableView.layoutIfNeeded()

          if isExpanded {
              expandedHeightConstraint.constant = expandedTableView.contentSize.height
              expandedTableView.fadeIn(Constants.animationDuration)
          } else {
              expandedHeightConstraint.constant = 0
              expandedTableView.fadeOut(Constants.animationDuration)
          }

          expandedTableView.layoutIfNeeded()
     }
```

The problem is that the content Size is not the correct one the first time, but then it is fixed automatically. In this gif you can see that the table shows 6 items, but I have 10 in total. The second time that the table is expanded, it shows 10 items.

[image]

How can I show all the items the first time based on the table's content size?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, since iOS 13, you can't use a tableView which is "not scrollable". Before this, sometimes, I used TableView within a UIScrollView with a height constraint which I updated based on contentSize but now it just glitches. It even shows you a warning in your console that the TableView is forced to render all cells or something along the lines. It basically can't compute the correct content size now. The only solution was that I had to rewrite those views and put all my views as tableViewCells and removed the ScrollView entirely. So I suggest to take a deep breath and start to refactor :)

*There is a hacky solution but I only write it down to discourage you about trying to find a hacky solution for this, as a bad example. You can read the "correct" content size after reloading the TableView and creating a 0.2 sec dispatch. After that the contentSize will be correct (most of time) but it is unreliable and there is a 99% chance that the user experience will be unacceptable.*